# How to save single channel EXR images with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a 32 bit single channel EXR image that I want to crop using ImageMagick, the problem is after I crop it it got saved into 32 bit 3 channel image by ImageMagick.

Below are the attempts that I tried that didn't work

```
mogrify -crop 200x100+238+200 test.exr -colorspace Y
```

This returns error mogrify: unrecognized image colorspace `Y'.

```
mogrify -crop 200x100+238+200 test.exr -channel Y
```

This returns 32 bit 3 channel image.

```
mogrify -crop 200x100+238+200 test.exr -separate
```

This returns 8 bit 1 channel image.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and my version of ImageMagick is 6.9.6-4 Q32 x86_64.

How can I make ImageMagick to save my EXR file with the original single channel 32 bit format?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect you are out of luck. I cannot get even version 7 of **ImageMagick** to read (identify) or write 32-bit OpenEXR files in any shape or form. It seems resolutely stuck on 16-bit in that respect. If anyone knows better, please correct me. If anyone else wants to try, there are some sample images here https://github.com/openexr/openexr-images/tree/master/TestImages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One expert from the ImageMagick forum actually posted an answer which works perfectly for me.

```
convert test.exr -crop 200x100+238+200 +repage -define exr:color-type=Y result.exr
```

Comment: This is an excellent find!  I don't understand why IM always gave me 3 channels without that `-define`; even using `-separate -channel R` options would create 3 channels for me before I found your answer.